# Google Search Console Page index chart not updating

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

[image: This is a screenshot from my Google Search Console account Index>Pages section. The chart got its last update on 8/23/2022 and is not getting new updates. It shows I have 0 pages indexed but in fact I have a few.]. The chart in the "Pages" section does not get updates. It's been almost a week.

When I search for my website on Google (site:mysite.com), I see it is getting indexed but GSC does not give the data.

Comment: What does it mean for a breadcrumb to be indexed?  The term "breadcrumbs" usually refers to the parent hierarchy links (Home > Category > Sub category > This page).  Google indexes whole pages, not just individual components of them (like breadcrumbs.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Dear @Community and Stephen, thank you for answering. I put a screenshot from GSC> Index> Pages section. The chart there does not get new updates and I do not know how to make it work properly.

Comment: What does the Breadcrumbs enhancement do?  Is that for identifying breadcrumb structured data in your pages?

Comment: I did not quite get what it does there. but what I mean is that the breadcrumbs sections gets updated but the pages section does not. How can I make it get updated?